# Objective c - XMPP PubSub ( XEP-0060 ) how can make auto-subscribe to node for user in my roster

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, publish-subscribe, xmppframework

i'm use xmppframework to implement xmpp inside my app.
I have a problem with PubSub module. 
I have the following behavior:
User "A" create a node where other users in the "A" roster can receive notifications published from.

I can create a node ( i set the node_id with "A" jabber id ), publish inside it, delete node, but i can't auto-subscribe to this node the users in roster of user "A".

How can i accomplish this goal ?

Server side Openfire ( it's true that OpenFire have all feature enabled ? )

Comment: Hi Pasquale, I have same requirement as described. Is there any way to achieve this?